# How to make CSS compatible with all browsers?

Tags: css, webkit, mozilla

Basically what I mean is which CSS fields need "-moz-" and "-webkit" in front of them for them to work? I know "border-radius" and "box-shadow" do, but can anyone tell me all of them? Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: are you having problems with specific ones, or you just want a list for future reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually quite a lot, many of which have to do with animation effects. My guess is you probably would only ever use a few (border, radius, opacity, etc.), but here is a full list of webkit properties: http://css-infos.net/properties/webkit.